# How to implement bootstrap Carousel in Umbraco 7

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, umbraco7

Im new to Umbraco 7. Just got an assigment to create my first .Net MVC site with Umbraco.

I have created a bootstrap Carousel - Only Im unable to fetch Images inside Media Picker and insert them inside the carousel.

Im listing my code below - Please help me on this, Thanks

[**Document Types** - HomeBase]

1. Name: Carousel Gallery
2. Alias: carouselGallery
3. DataType: Media Picker

This is the Page that will host the Carosel [HomeBase.cshtml]

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.HomeBase>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}

<div class="wrapper">

    <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

            @Umbraco.RenderMacro("GalleryImages")


            @*<div class="item active">
                <img src="//placehold.it/1800x900" data-color="firebrick" alt="First Image">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>First Image</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="//placehold.it/1800x900" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Second Image</h3>
                </div>
            </div>*@

        </div>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    @RenderBody()

</div>
```

This is the Macro Partial View [GalleryImages.cshtml]

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@if (CurrentPage.HasValue("carouselGallery"))
{
    var carouselGalleryList = CurrentPage.carouselGallery.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var carouselGalleryCollection = Umbraco.Media(carouselGalleryList);

    foreach (var carouselGalleryImage in carouselGalleryCollection)
    {
        <img src="@carouselGalleryImage.Url" />
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe this https://www.systenics.com/blog/adding-bootstrap-based-responsive-carousel-to-umbraco-7/ can help.

Comment: Thanks ZiMtyth - But I already test that one prior to posting here on Stackoverflow

It did not work

Comment: which version exactly are you using?

Comment: Im using Umbraco 7.6.5

Comment: You should have the property value converter enabled example in your template page: 
 var slides = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("carouselGallery")

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Do any images render on the screen?